# Problemas graficando mapas en R (no correspondencia entre valores y polígonos)

Tags: base-de-datos, r

Tengo la siguiente base de datos:

```
dput(base_mapa)
structure(list(Municipio = structure(1:46, .Label = c("Abasolo", 
"Acámbaro", "Apaseo el Alto", "Apaseo el Grande", "Atarjea", 
"Celaya", "Comonfort", "Coroneo", "Cortazar", "Cuerámaro", "Doctor Mora", 
"Dolores Hidalgo Cuna de la Independencia Nacional", "Guanajuato", 
"Huanímaro", "Irapuato", "Jaral del Progreso", "Jerécuaro", "León", 
"Manuel Doblado", "Moroleón", "Ocampo", "Pénjamo", "Pueblo Nuevo", 
"Purísima del Rincón", "Romita", "Salamanca", "Salvatierra", 
"San Diego de la Unión", "San Felipe", "San Francisco del Rincón", 
"San José Iturbide", "San Luis de la Paz", "San Miguel de Allende", 
"Santa Catarina", "Santa Cruz de Juventino Rosas", "Santiago Maravatío", 
"Silao de la Victoria", "Tarandacuao", "Tarimoro", "Tierra Blanca", 
"Uriangato", "Valle de Santiago", "Victoria", "Villagrán", "Xichú", 
"Yuriria"), class = "factor"), esc_padres = c(3.86098699235428, 
5.18996103065201, 3.76708657196462, 4.99756716733658, 2.7012987012987, 
7.47304809016268, 4.3155465495891, 3.7196044211751, 5.4, 4.24333781965007, 
3.22845691382766, 4.14853328198216, 7.77708669642009, 4.15438210487715, 
7.03142595052825, 5.17823529411765, 2.8901565013895, 7.26941131493679, 
3.63011363636364, 5.3295894655306, 2.91205936920223, 4.09106364892147, 
4.22334384858044, 4.43257619321449, 3.8210624417521, 6.50501821012539, 
4.82928576079172, 2.81486486486486, 3.38119337196964, 5.3712441221009, 
4.30972972972973, 4.05120554793968, 6.05751400916964, 3.01430615164521, 
4.25351621527374, 3.59549624687239, 5.12189810304315, 4.85124404446797, 
3.70584806683505, 2.94416749750748, 4.79890492782479, 4.32016828819353, 
3.72265148434323, 5.27143810477144, 2.29485570890841, 3.68035955924995
), esc_hijos = c(8.06955544455544, 9.42569151429911, 8.46016691957511, 
9.26089259700702, 8.21449275362319, 10.6699615986346, 9.00463939266132, 
8.24451754385965, 9.46174715138361, 8.4865671641791, 9.11782850092535, 
8.83514492753623, 11.1484923928077, 8.4, 10.4846150799937, 9.28786057692308, 
7.27063829787234, 10.3757437871894, 7.59277403551745, 9.31464872944693, 
7.54629061925199, 8.43529778609292, 8.57988721804511, 7.87466808284652, 
8.0863646507476, 10.2467491278148, 9.2043320529236, 7.21696252465483, 
8.22153510367406, 8.8647701942469, 9.44823151125402, 9.51300503752442, 
9.50975238622216, 8.16164383561644, 8.81864754098361, 8.09672386895476, 
9.16986899563319, 9.45281220209723, 8.33889077917659, 8.11371841155235, 
8.4953830369357, 8.68868367506652, 9.25738396624473, 9.84020379805465, 
7.2531847133758, 7.90748695918994), razon_esc = c(2.09002399141338, 
1.81613916918273, 2.24581165257451, 1.85308016619265, 3.04094202898551, 
1.42779244424779, 2.08655828159673, 2.21650385641144, 1.75217539840437, 
1.99997443636928, 2.82420634510351, 2.12970327751953, 1.43350496503267, 
2.02196133815871, 1.49110794222415, 1.79363432702138, 2.51565556895512, 
1.42731554697831, 2.09160781069193, 1.74772349534423, 2.59139312167229, 
2.06188378132829, 2.03153887669577, 1.77654432537477, 2.11626079762248, 
1.57520683214464, 1.90594065227042, 2.56387530880681, 2.43154833196801, 
1.65041282666176, 2.19230255811112, 2.34819115568264, 1.56991009378214, 
2.70763599482482, 2.07326059068898, 2.25190719528572, 1.79032632261562, 
1.94853363703205, 2.25019769531414, 2.75586168871893, 1.77027533670821, 
2.01119102207467, 2.48677159416602, 1.86670195162641, 3.1606277837947, 
2.14856370196652), diff_esc = c(4.20856845220116, 4.2357304836471, 
4.69308034761049, 4.26332542967044, 5.51319405232449, 3.19691350847194, 
4.68909284307222, 4.52491312268455, 4.06174715138361, 4.24322934452904, 
5.8893715870977, 4.68661164555408, 3.37140569638765, 4.24561789512285, 
3.45318912946542, 4.10962528280543, 4.38048179648284, 3.10633247225256, 
3.96266039915382, 3.98505926391634, 4.63423125004977, 4.34423413717145, 
4.35654336946467, 3.44209188963203, 4.2653022089955, 3.74173091768939, 
4.37504629213188, 4.40209765978997, 4.84034173170443, 3.493526072146, 
5.13850178152429, 5.46179948958473, 3.45223837705252, 5.14733768397123, 
4.56513132570987, 4.50122762208236, 4.04797089259003, 4.60156815762926, 
4.63304271234154, 5.16955091404487, 3.69647810911092, 4.36851538687299, 
5.5347324819015, 4.56876569328322, 4.95832900446739, 4.22712739993998
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-46L))
```

Quiero hacer distintos mapas para las variables de mi base de datos. El siguiente código descarga el mapa y alimenta la base de datos final para crearlo:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)


#Descargar mapa
mapgto <- read_sf("http://geoinfo.iplaneg.net/geoserver/wms/kml?layers=geonode%3Amgm_gto2010&mode=download") %>%
  st_collection_extract("POLYGON")

esc_map <- append_data(mapgto, base_mapa)

#Creamos el mapa
tm_shape(esc_map) +
    tm_polygons("esc_padres", id="Municipio", 
    auto.palette.mapping=FALSE, palette="Purples", n=5)
```

Todo parecería estar bien:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, al revisar con detenimiento el siguiente mapa con nombres: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me di cuenta que el color de relleno no corresponde en todos los casos a la variable utilizada. Por ejemplo, el municipio en la parte superior derecha está en color fuerte cuando debería ser el más claro y así en otros casos.

Le he dado vueltas a mi código y no encuentro el error, en particular porque cosas como esta:

```
mapgto$Name
```

no me permiten visualizar si las coordenadas corresponden a los municipios.
Cualquier orientación para corregir este error, ya sea con las librerías utilizadas o con otras, la agradeceré mucho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que el problema lo tienes en "matching" del `sf` con el `data.frame` de los municipios. Al hacer esto:

```
esc_map <- append_data(mapgto, base_mapa)
```

El mapeo es según el orden de ambos objetos, por lo que si no tienen el mismo orden los datos espaciales no coincidirán con los datos del municipio. Una posibilidad sería reordenar uno de los objetos para que coincidan los ordénes y otra forma mejor es hacer un "match" más preciso usando el nombre del municipio que en el `sf` esta oculto en un conjunto de entidades html de la variable `mapgto$Description`. Vamos entonces a recuperar el nombre del Municipio usando expresiones regulares:

```
# Creamos una nueva columna Municipio solo con este dato extraído del HTML
pattern <- '(?<=NOM_MUN</span>:</strong> <span class=\\\"atr-value\\\">)(.+?)(?=</span>)'
mapgto$Municipio <- regmatches(mapgto$Description, regexpr(pattern, mapgto$Description, perl=TRUE))
# Hacemos consistente el nombre del municipio "Silao de la Victoria"
mapgto$Municipio[mapgto$Municipio == 'Silao'] <- 'Silao de la Victoria'
```

Y ahora sí, podemos combinar la información, pero deberemos indicar la columna por la que haremos el "match":

```
esc_map <- append_data(mapgto, base_mapa, key.shp = "Municipio", key.data = "Municipio")
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Perdona por molestar, pero me chirría un pequeño detalle de tu respuesta, que no tiene nada que ver con la solución (Ya que no tengo ni idea de R). No es un shapefile sino un archivo kml. Los atributos en un shapefile (formato que liberó ESRI) se almacenan en un segundo archivo de extensión .dbf, y que "engancha" al .shp mediante otro archivo .shx . Por otra parte supongo que en R habrá librerías para leer KML y no tener que recurrir a expresiones regulares. Saludos.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo, si tienes razón, es una deformación mía decirle shapefile a cualquier cosa que tenga polígonos, en realidad en la visión de R estos datos se denomina `simple features` o "layers"

Comment: Si se entiende perfectamente lo que quieres decir, pero a mi me choca un poco, ya que trabajo regularmente con información geográfica. Pues veo que R también "se hace la picha un lío". Ya que layers es un concepto muy general, features hace referencia a un "contenedor de geometrías" (Punto línea, polígono, (las demás añadiendole el concepto de multi) y multigeometría). Pero al hablar de formatos que includo no tienen nada que ver (uno almacena los datos en binario, el otro basado en XML) creo que convendría diferenciarlos. Pero que vamos, esto no le quita calidad a tu respuesta. Saludos!! =)

Comment: Genial tu respuesta. Gracias por hacerme recordar que me urge repasar expresiones regulares. Abrazo.

Comment: Alejandro, no sé si en los datos que estás usando están incluidos, si es así es muy recomendable usar los códigos de INEGI para hacer joins de cartografía. Los nombres de municipio con frecuencia están repetidos (Benito Juárez ), cambia la nomenclatura (Silao, Silao de la Victoria) o cambia la ortografía (Cuahutlalpan, Cuautlalpan), etc. La clave numérica es más confiable y la manejan casi todas bases de datos oficiales con unidades territoriales.

Answer (score 2):

Parece ser que `append_data` une los datos por una llave o si no la encuentra por siguiendo el orden que tiene cada conjunto. En este caso no encuentra la llave y el error se da porque los municipios en `mapgto` no tiene el mismo orden que los de `base_mapa`, enseguida una solución particular para este caso:

```
#Tomando base mapa como en tu ejemplo    
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)


#Descargar mapa
mapgto <- read_sf("http://geoinfo.iplaneg.net/geoserver/wms/kml?layers=geonode%3Amgm_gto2010&mode=download") %>%
     st_collection_extract("POLYGON")


esc_map <- append_data(mapgto, base_mapa)

#Comparemos los municipios en esc_map$Description vs esc_map$Municipio
library(rvest)
mun<-NULL
for(i in 1:46){
     web<-read_html(esc_map$Description[i])
     m<-web%>%html_nodes(".atr-value")%>%html_text()
     mun<-cbind(mun,m[2])
}

df<-data.frame(Municipio=esc_map$Municipio,mun=t(mun))#Son diferentes

#Una solucion es extraer los municipos de mapgto y despues hacer un merge
mun<-NULL
for(i in 1:46){
     web<-read_html(mapgto$Description[i])
     m<-web%>%html_nodes(".atr-value")%>%html_text()
     mun<-cbind(mun,m[2])
}

mapgto$Municipio<-t(mun)

#Combinasmos los datos

esc_map <- merge(mapgto,base_mapa)#Se pierde un municipio

mapgto$Municipio[!mapgto$Municipio%in%esc_map$Municipio]
base_mapa$Municipio[!base_mapa$Municipio%in%esc_map$Municipio]

#Es silao

mapgto$Municipio[!mapgto$Municipio%in%esc_map$Municipio]<-
     as.character(base_mapa$Municipio[!base_mapa$Municipio%in%esc_map$Municipio])

#Ya corregido el municipo faltante, unimos de nuevo
esc_map <- merge(mapgto,base_mapa)

#Creamos el mapa
tm_shape(esc_map) +
     tm_polygons("esc_padres", id="Municipio", 
                 auto.palette.mapping=FALSE, palette="Purples", n=5)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!